# Webview Not Refresh Image

Tags: ios, swift

I am Load Html File to webview using load html string method. All works fine. in my code user choose image as profile and choosen image save on fix path and name. when user choose image and when web view reload at that time image show old image. image updated to directory but not show.
This problem only occure in Ipad, In Iphone work fine.

Have any Suggestion.? then please suggest

//My Loading Code

```
 webview.loadHTMLString(invoiceHTML, baseURL: NSURL(string:resumeComposer.HTMLFilePath)! as URL)
```

//Image Source update to HTML String code

```
imgPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: folderpathforNormal).appendingPathComponent("ProfileImg.png").path
HTMLContent = HTMLContent?.replacingOccurrences(of: "*userimage*", with: imgPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

clear the UIWebview cache first like this:

```
//to remove cache from UIWebview
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
    if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
        for cookie in cookies {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not working here...problem only happen in ipad. for ipad in simulator it is work fine. Any suggestion?